# How can I reuse a background in Google Slides?

Tags: images, google-slides

I chose a background image for one slide, and then when I wanted to use it for another, I had to upload it all over again. How can I just re-use a background from somewhere else in the deck?

Comment: Worth mentioning: when I select "choose", one of the options is "Your albums", which contains a bunch of random photos from my blogspot account and my phone. I suppose I could upload my background to there, and use it that way, but I would have had to think of doing that first, and I'm not sure that this isn't just another way of uploading my image twice.

Comment: One more mention: you can set the background of your Master slides, and that will apply the background to all your slides. That's probably the best solution if you want **all** your slides to use the same background, but doesn't solve the question of re-using it for just certain slides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to apply that image to all slides you can change the "master slide". If you just want to apply it to some of the slides, I think the easiest way is just to copy that slide with the image you wanted and paste it. The pasted slide will look exactly the same as the original. Then you can delete the content/change the layout etc., but the background image will still be there.